# Identity involving logarithms

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, asymptotics

Here's a picture from the book,

[image]

I don't get why the expression $$ n^{\log_ba-\epsilon} \sum_{j=0}^{\log_bn-1} a^j \left(\frac{1}{b^j}\right)^{\log_ba-\epsilon} = \sum_{j=0}^{\log_ba-1} \frac{(ab^\epsilon)}{(b^{\log_ba})^j} \text{ ?}$$

Comment: Please write an *informative* title.

Comment: I don't think ur title was much more informative than mine lol

Comment: Huh???   I didn't *write* a title!

Answer (score 1):

They didn't show few simplification steps in between:
$$ a^j\left(\frac{1}{b^j}\right)^{\log_ba-\epsilon} = \dfrac{a^j}{b^{j\log_ba -j\epsilon}}=\dfrac{a^j}{b^{j\log_ba}\cdot b^{ -j\epsilon}}=\dfrac{a^jb^{j\epsilon }}{b^{j\log_ba}}=\frac{(ab^\epsilon)^j}{(b^{\log_ba})^j} $$

Comment: ok, where are you getting $a^j$$1^{log_ba-\epsilon}$ = $a^j$ = $a^jb^{j\epsilon}$ ?

Comment: Ah ok. I'll add few more steps... $b^{j\epsilon}$ came from the denominator.. was using this exponent rule: $$x^{m-n} = x^m\cdot x^{-n} = \dfrac{x^m}{x^n}$$

Comment: updated.. see if it makes sense now:) @randomvalue

Comment: yes, thank you!